# Error continues to pop up when trying to run a file with Javafx on command prompt about class file version?

Tags: java, javafx, version

So I have been following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129569/how-to-run-javafx-application-from-command-line) to try and run a java file on command prompt. However, this error keeps coming up

> C:\Users\blued\OneDrive\Documents>javac --module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-21.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml HangmanGUI.java
> error: cannot access module-info
> bad class file: C:\javafx-sdk-21.0.1\lib\javafx.fxml.jar(/module-info.class)
> class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0
> Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
> error: cannot access module-info
> bad class file: C:\javafx-sdk-21.0.1\lib\javafx.controls.jar(/module-info.class)
> class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 55.0
> Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
> 2 errors

> C:\Users\blued\OneDrive\Documents>java  --module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-21.0.1\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml HangmanGUI.java
> Unrecognized option: --module-path
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

[image: image of error if that is more clear]

I've never heard of a class file version before but I looked it up and saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)

so apparently I should have class file version 55.0 because I have java 11 installed. That is what comes up when I check the version on command prompt. How would I change it from 61 and why would it be that in the first place? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"How would I change it from 61"*  - recompile it using a Java 11 compiler.  *"Why would it be that in the first place?"* - because you compiled it using a Java 17 compiler!!  (If you are using an IDE ... make sure that you have Java 11 installed and that your IDE knows to use it for this project.  Details will be IDE specific ... and easily discoverable via the duplink or a a Google search.)

Comment: You didn't compile the code which isn't working in your environment. It isn't your code - it is the JavaFX SDK, so you don't need to compile it, but you do need to run it in the correct environment.  You are using JavaFX 21.  See the [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction) site for how to use it.  Including ["Installing Java"](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-java) -> "JavaFX 21 needs at least JDK 17." and ["Run HelloWorld using JavaFX SDK"](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx), which provides an example of running a JavaFX app from the command line.

Comment: Also `.java` is a source file.  You don't run source files in Java, (unless in the very rare case it is a [single file source code program](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330).  Instead you run class files.  To do that, you don't provide any extension to the name of the class you are trying to run.  Again, the openjfx documentation referenced provides an example: `java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX`.